# Typecast Generic type to other type

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe4

i have a base class

```
 TEventMulticaster = class(Tobject)
 public
   procedure Notify(aMap: WideString);
 end;

 procedure TEventMulticaster.Notify(aMap: WideString);
 begin
  // Do something 
 end;
```

And a derived generic class

```
  TEventMulticaster<T> = class(TEventMulticaster)
   public
     procedure Notify(aMap: T ); reintroduce;
   end;


  procedure TEventMulticaster<T>.Notify(aMap: T);
  begin
    inherited Notify(aMap)  // ERROR
  end;
```

when base class Notify is call it give me error **"Incompatible types: 'WideString' and 'T'"** 
and when i do  `**Notify(WideString(aMap))**` it says invalid typecast

my question is how can i type cast generic type to "**WideString**" so that i can call base class `notify`

Comment: You cannot typecast an arbitrary generic argument to a `WideString`. Why would you want to do so. What would you expect to happen if `aMap` was, say, a `TMainForm`, the class representing the main form of your application? You have to get into the mindset that when implementing a generic method, the generic type can be absolutely anything. Now, you can apply constraints, but they are somewhat limited. Also, why are you using `WideString`. Unless you are calling COM methods you should stop using that. Use `string`, an alias for `UnicodeString`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me, but well, `inherited Notify(WideString(TValue.From<T>(aMap).AsString));`. Or `inherited Notify(TValue.From<T>(aMap).AsType<WideString>);`.

Comment: i am doing this because more than 10 classes are derive from base class which is "TEventMulticaster" and all are doing same thing but there types are different so i make generic class with generic function and do my operation . and aMap is not of type class.

Comment: The answer to your question is that you cannot do this. That's not very helpful to you. Unless you present the underlying problem it's hard for us to give you more general advice, which I think is what you need. As regards your statement that "aMap is not of type class" that doesn't really hold any currency to the compiler. As far as it is concerned, `T` can be anything, because you said it could be anything. That's pretty much the raison d'etre of generics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
procedure TEventMulticaster<T>.Notify(aMap: T);
begin
  inherited Notify(aMap);
end;
```

Here you have `aMap` which is a generic argument, of type `T`. The type `T` has no constraints on it. It can be any type. You are seeking to convert `aMap` to `WideString`. The compiler simply has no way to do that. There is no over-arching conversion that can take an argument of arbitrary type and convert it to `WideString`.

You could push `aMap` into a `TValue`, and then call the `ToString` method of `TValue`. The compiler will at least be satisfied with this:

```
inherited Notify(TValue.From<T>(aMap).ToString);
```

This might do what you expect. Or perhaps not. It all depends upon what `T` happens to be. If `T` is a fundamental type like `Integer` or `string` then `TValue.ToString` will almost certainly do what you expect. If `T` is more esoteric then who knows whether this code will behave as you expect. You certainly have not given us any indication as to how the arbitrary type is to be converted to text.

---

The thing that I suspect you are not grasping about generics is that the compiler has to know how to compile the method without knowing what the generic type is. In comments you state that:

> aMap is not of type class

Whilst you might know that, the compiler does not. From the perspective of the compiler, `T` can be anything at all. Generics are very different from Smalltalk/C++ templates where the compilation happens after instantiation.

The generics functionality does allow you to apply constraints to your generic type. However, these are quite limited. You cannot apply a constraint that says, *type T will have a well-defined implicit conversion to `WideString`*.

As I have said to you before, I sense that you are struggling with your understanding of generics. I feel that it would be more productive for you to present the underlying *problem* rather than you proposed *solution*.

---

One final point. The `WideString` type is a wrapper around the COM `BSTR` string type. In modern Unicode aware Delphi you use `WideString` just when writing interop code with COM. You should be using `string` rather than `WideString`. The `string` type is an alias for `UnicodeString`, the native Delphi Unicode string type.

Comment: pushing to tvalue and then call the base function does the trick and big thanks......

Comment: if T is of type array of record then how can i extract it

Comment: Well, this is pretty much what I was getting at. You can't expect TValue to be able to handle everything. I think you may need to ask a new question. I urge you to present the problem you face rather than asking about your solution.

Comment: Essentially, generics cater for compile time variance. You are looking for runtime variance. That probably means you need RTTI.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this?

```
TEventMulticaster = class
end;

TEventMulticaster<T> = class( TEventMulticaster )
public
  procedure Notify( AMsg : T );
end;

TEventMaster = class
private
  FEvents : TList<TEventMulticaster>;
public
  procedure Notify<T>( AMsg : T );
end;

procedure TEventMaster.Notify<T>( AMsg : T );
var
  LEvent : TEventMulticaster;
begin
  for LEvent in FEvents do
    if LEvent is TEventMulticaster<T> then
      ( LEvent as TEventMulticaster<T> ).Notify( AMsg );
end;
```

Comment: not exactly what i expect as in my question i am calling non generic function of my base class .